# Erro no Composer ao tentar criar um projeto CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, composer

Estou usando uma máquina virtual Linux(Ubuntu) para desenvolver um projeto CakePHP. Já instalei tudo que ele precisa (Apache, PHP, MySQL, Curl, Git, INTL e o Composer).

Até o momento, tudo certo, até eu tentar criar o projeto do CakePHP com o Composer. Ele simplesmente para e mostra a mensagem abaixo:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]  
  Content-Length mismatch                   


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Já pesquisei em diversos lugares, mas parece ser um problema meio genérico do Composer, e até o momento não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar. Se alguém souber de algo, please, me dá um help. Agradeço.

Segue imagem do erro no Terminal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual a versão do php? verifica se a extensão mbstring está instalada.

Comment: Estou usando a versão 5.6 do PHP.
Não encontrei o pacote mbstring para instalar pelo apt-get. Como sei se está instalado?

Comment: Executa o comando `php -i | grep mbstring` ou `php --re mbstring` ou `php --ri mbstring` .

Comment: Parece estar instalado. Quando rodo o comando acima ele mostra várias linhas com valores para `mbstring.detect_order`, mbstring.encoding...`, etc.